# how to include stylesheet in root folder of rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, stylesheet, sass, compass-sass

Due to some heroku problems with rails 3 and compass framework, we followed this guide:

http://lds.li/post/673242899/compass-with-rails-3-on-heroku

and moved our stylesheets to app_name/tmp/stylesheets.

I tried using

```
stylesheet_link_tag "#{Rails.root}/tmp/stylesheets/main.css"
```

but that doesnt work as it looks for the css file in

http://localhost:3000/app_name/tmp/stylesheets/main.css

I know this is a simple fix and I'm overlooking something simple but hopefully someone can answer this with one look. Thanks in advance!

I would like to point out that we have this in our stylesheets.rb

```
Rails.configuration.middleware.insert_before('Rack::Sendfile', 'Rack::Static',
                                         :urls => ['/stylesheets/compiled'],
                                         :root => "#{Rails.root}/tmp")
```

WHen I try "compass watch" it still compiles to "tmp/stylesheets/main.css" instead of stylesheets/compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally take a different approach to solving this problem:

Stick the following code in your compass initializer:

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:never_update] = true
```

This prevents sass from trying to write to your filesystem when the server is hit.

Just make sure that you are running **compass watch** in development mode and commit the compiled stylesheets to yout git repo

This saves so much time - if you don't like this approach, try [hassle](http://github.com/pedro/hassle) or one of the [recent forks](http://github.com/pedro/hassle/network)

Comment: which compass initializer is this? the one in initializers or the one in config?

Comment: The easiest way is to stick it in initializers/compass.rb [**like so**](http://pastie.org/1129125) - please note that I'm using compass-0.10.5, where the initializer file has a slightly different format from previous versionss).  A far better solution (and the one [advised by the guy who wrote Sass](http://nex-3.com/posts/88-sass-supports-rack)) is to leave initializers/compass.rb as it is, and put the [**following code**](http://pastie.org/1129078) into your config.ru file (the rack file at the root of your rails3 app).  I think the rack approach might be better tbh but both work fine

Answer (score 1):

Change your `config/compass.rb` to set `css_dir = "tmp/stylesheets/compiled"`

Based on what you have in your configuration, you should be using this for your template:

`stylesheet_link_tag "compiled/main.css"`

(Which renders `<link rel="/stylesheets/compiled/main.css" ...`)

(The `tmp` dir is outside of `public`; it shouldn't appear in the URLs because the middleware is taking care of remapping it.)

Comment: it was originally compiled/main.css but rails keeps looking into the public/stylesheets/compiled directory instead of app_name/tmp/stylesheets. i think the middleware isn't redirecting to for me? how can i check this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "rails keeps looking"? There are two questions here: First, is the sass being compiled to tmp/stylesheets/compiled/*.css? And second, is that folder being served as /stylesheets/compiled over http, as if it were in /public?

Comment: sass is being compiled to app_root/tmp/stylesheets/compiled/*.css, and i included the stylesheet using the link_tag you said. when i look at the source of the generated page, it looks for http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/compiled/main.css, as if it was still looking at public(the changes i make to the css are in tmp, so i don't see any new styles when i refresh)

Comment: Then that part is correct: it should be looking at public. I couldn't find any docs for the middleware.insert_before options, but that *should* publish what you have in /tmp as if it were a path under public. I'll have another look & get back to you.